# Чем заменить метод .replace() ? нужно апнуть только указанный порядковый символ?

Tags: java, строки, char

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MexicanWave {
    public static String[] wave(String str) {
        List <String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (int i=0; i<str.length();i++){
            if (Character.isLetter(str.charAt(i))){
            list.add(str.replace(str.charAt(i), Character.toUpperCase(str.charAt(i))));
        }
       System.out.println(list);
    }
//        return new String[] {};
    return list.toArray(new String[0]);
   }
}
```

получил результат

```
[Cool]
[Cool, cOOl]
[Cool, cOOl, cOOl]
[Cool, cOOl, cOOl, cooL]
```

я хочу перевести в верхний регистр по одному символу но переводится повторяющийся символ. Как лучше заменить .replace() ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Метод `String.replace` заменяет все вхождения искомого символа.
Для того чтобы заменить один символ, вы можете разбить строку на подстроки:

```
list.add(str.substring(0,i)+ Character.toUpperCase(str.charAt(i))+str.substring(i+1));
```